# Returning activityLauncher result from activity to activity to fragment in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good morning lads,
Got myself quite the confusing problem, atleast for myself:

I have a fragment (page 1) which contains a button that opens an activity (page 2) using activityLauncher so it returns a result, and within that same activity, a button for the exact same purposes (page 3).

### **profile_fragment.java** (page 1) + including the intent launch

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {

                    if (result.getResultCode() == 111) {
                        Intent intent = result.getData();

                        if (intent != null) {
                            item = (ExerciseItemFinal) intent.getSerializableExtra("siu");
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

```
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExerciseCategoryChooser.class);
                activityLauncher.launch(intent);
            }
        });
```

### **ExerciseCategoryChooser.java** (page 2) including the intent launch

```
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityLauncher2 = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {

                    if (result.getResultCode() == 011) {
                        Intent intent = result.getData();

                        if (intent != null) {
                            item = (ExerciseItemFinal) intent.getSerializableExtra("code123");
                            Intent i = new Intent();
                            i.putExtra("siu", item);
                            setResult(111, intent);
                            finish();


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseCategoryChooser.this, ConfirmAdditionExercise.class);

        activityLauncher2.launch(intent);

    }
```

### **ConfirmAdditionExercise.java** (page 3)

```
        bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ExerciseItemFinal item = new ExerciseItemFinal("Siuu", "10.5", "5");

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("code123", item);
                setResult(011, intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

The problem with my code is that I am able to return the result of page 3 to page 2, so inside of page 2 I can use the object to do whatever I need, but returning the same object from page 2 to page 1, just won't work for some reason, whenever I try to use "item.getName()" it gives me a NullPointerException (which doesn't happen on the 2nd page):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.poop123, PID: 23789
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.poop123.ExerciseItemFinal.getName()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.poop123.profile_fragment$1.onActivityResult(profile_fragment.java:66)
        at com.example.poop123.profile_fragment$1.onActivityResult(profile_fragment.java:57)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:148)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3026)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:262)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:510)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1433)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7923)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3332)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I have all classes using `Implements Serializable` even if they don't require, and most confusing of all, I have a separate process for a different fragment which is basically the same thing, the only thing changing is the type of object being passed, but working.

I would be very embarressed if the solution is simple and obvious...

Comment: Where did you call "item.getName" in your page 2 ?
your error appeared cause this line right ? "Toast.makeText(getContext(), item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();"

Comment: Hi @LouisChabert, thanks for your response,
I don't have any Toast on my second page, but I can guarantee you that when I use it, it shows the toast with no problem.
Now on page 1, whenever I try to invoke item.getName() on a Toast, or anywhere for that matter, it will give me this NullPointerException.

Comment: Ok well, item is an element of view right ? does it have an ID ?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I don't quite understand what you mean by element, but I can tell you that, item is an object of the class ExerciseItemFinal, which is made of 3 atributes: Name, Weight, Reps. all the items are declared outside the OnCreateView or OnCreate methods, but inicialized within the previous code blocks I showed you. Edit: Apart from the last activity, where I declare and inicialize the variable immediately.

Comment: It's my fault I didn't really understand what "item" meant, unfortunately I'm not sure I can help you, I upvoted, I hope someone else can help you

Comment: I appreciate it!